# developing plugins: DX or VST?

Tags: c++, plugins, audio, directx, vst

I'd like to get into plugin development using C++. Am undecided between developing VSTs or DXs. What are the considerations? I know that some hosts more readily support one format or the other (Cubase:VSTs, Cakewalk:DXs), but that's all I'm aware of.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go VST all the way. Many more hosts support it, and it makes it easier to port to other platforms to the future (ie, Mac OSX or Linux). With DX you are essentially tied to Windows and the small handful of hosts which support it.

Furthermore, VST is much more widespread, meaning that there is a larger number of plugin developers who can help you out if you have questions, and more example source code on the net.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'd like to have a balanced opinion, so I have to ask -- are there any downsides to VSTs as well?

Comment: Agree too - VST has the benefit it works on multiple architectures (namely Mac, *nix and Windows). If you're developing just for Mac OS X, you might look into Audio Units. It's very similar to VST, the benefit being OS X comes with some nifty development tools to test your plugin. The downside: it's only for Macs. To get the VST SDK you have to create an account at Steinberg - quite hassly to navigate, but you'll get there eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every major DAW supports VST plugins nowadays (including Cakewalk/Sonar). DX plugins are pretty much deprecated.

Also, having written some plugins for both architectures, I find VST API simpler and cleaner. It also has a much larger developer base, check out http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33 for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the forum links, these look like they'll be helpful. I've decided to go the VST route :)